# ng-click event not defined after $compile in google maps infowindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-service, angularjs-compile

Within this angular google map, I want to give the ability for a link to appear in a dynamic infowindow thats generated when the user searchs an address.
Now Ive got the infowindow to load correctly but the ng-click event is coming back undefined.

I have compiled the HTML string but still having no joy. Here is the  compile code:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', function () {
        var contentString2 = "<div><a ng-click='hello()'>Click me!</a></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(contentString2)($q);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: compiled[0]
        });
        this.selectedMarker = this.marker;

        infowindow.open(this.map, this.marker);
    });

};
```

The infowindow loads fine when the marker is selected but when the "ng-click" is clicked inside the infowindow it comes back with:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I've provided a jsbin link to show the code:

http://jsbin.com/zukefa/edit

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's working fine in your provided `jsbin`...

Comment: Its not firing the alert when you click "Click me" in the info window